# Segmentation fault in CS50 (2020) recovery program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

I am trying to write a program that will recover deleted images from a file and write each of those images to their own seperate files. I've been stuck on this problem for a few days, and have tried my best to solve it on my own, but I now realize I need some guidance. My code always compiles well, but everytime I run my program I suffer a segmentation fault. Using valgrind shows me that I don't have any memory leaks.

I think I have pinpointed the issue, though I'm not sure how to resolve it. When I run my program through the debugger, it always stops at the code inside my last 'else' condition (where the comment says "If already found JPEG") , and gives me an error message about the segmentation fault.

I have tried opening and initializing my file pointer jpegn atop this line of code, to prevent jpegn from being NULL when this condition is run, but that did not work to fix the fault.

I am very new to programming (and this site) so any advice or suggestions would be helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc!=2) // Checks if the user typed in exactly 1 command-line argument
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    if(fopen(argv[1],"r") == NULL) // Checks if the image can be opened for reading 
    {
        printf("This image cannot be opened for reading\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    FILE *forensic_image = fopen(argv[1],"r");  // Opens the image inputted and stores it in a new file
    
    BYTE *buffer = malloc(512 * sizeof(BYTE)); // Dynamically creates an array capable of holding 512 bytes of data
    
    if(malloc(512*sizeof(BYTE)) == NULL) // Checks if there is enough memory in the system
    {
        printf("System error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Creates a counting variable, a string and two file pointers
    
    int JPEG_num=0;
    char *filename = NULL;
   
    FILE *jpeg0 = NULL;
    FILE *jpegn = NULL;
    
    while(!feof(forensic_image))    // Repeat until end of image
    {
        fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, forensic_image); // Read 512 bytes of data from the image into a buffer
        
        // Check for the start of a new JPEG file
        
        if(buffer[0] == 0xff & buffer[1] == 0xd8 & buffer[2] == 0xff & (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            // If first JPEG
            
            if(JPEG_num == 0)
            {
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", JPEG_num);
                jpeg0 = fopen(filename, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, jpeg0);
            }
            else    // If not first JPEG
            {
                fclose(jpeg0);
                JPEG_num++;
                
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", JPEG_num);
                jpegn = fopen(filename, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, jpegn);
             }
            
        }
        else    // If already found JPEG
        {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, jpegn);
        }
        
        
    }
    
    // Close remaining files and free dynamically allocated memory

    fclose(jpegn);
    
    free(buffer);
    
}
```

Comment: You may find [cs50 pset4 Recover - why does writing entire file to memory fail check50?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62608167/3422102) helpful.

Comment: regarding: `if(JPEG_num == 0)
            {
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", JPEG_num);
                jpeg0 = fopen(filename, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, jpeg0);
            }`   this fails to increment `JPEG_num` so execution will never reach the `else` code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled1.c" -o "untitled1.o"
```

results in several warnings like:

```
untitled1.c:46:91: warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of ‘&’ [-Wparentheses]

if(buffer[0] == 0xff & buffer[1] == 0xd8 & buffer[2] == 0xff & (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
```

Note: a single `&` is a bit wise AND. You really want a logical AND `&&` for all but the last one in this statement

regarding;

```
FILE *forensic_image = fopen(argv[1],"r");
```

Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful. If not successful (==NULL) then call

```
perror( "fopen failed" );
```

to output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

regarding:

```
while(!feof(forensic_image))
```

please read: [why while( !feof() is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

regarding:

```
FILE *forensic_image = fopen(argv[1],"r");
```

This is already done in the prior code block. There is absolutely no reason to do this again AND it will create problems in the code. Suggest: replacing:

```
if(fopen(argv[1],"r") == NULL)      
{         
    printf("This image cannot be opened for reading\n");
    return 1;     
}
```

with:

```
if( (forensic_image = fopen(argv[1],"r") ) == NULL)      
{         
    perror( "fopen for input file failed" );         
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );     
}
```

regarding:

```
BYTE *buffer = malloc( 512 * sizeof(BYTE) );
```

and later:

```
free( buffer );
```

This is a waste of code and resources. The project only needs one such instance. Suggest:

```
#define RECORD_LEN 512
```

and

```
unsigned char buffer[ RECORD_LEN ];
```

regarding;

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, forensic_image);
```

The function: `fread()` returns a `size_t`. You should be assigning the returned value to a `size_t` variable and checking that value to assure the operation was successful. Infact, that statement should be in the `while()` condition

regarding;

```
sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", JPEG_num);
```

This results in undefined behavior and can result in a seg fault event because the pointer `filename` is initialized to NULL. Suggest:

```
char filename[20];
```

to avoid that problem

regarding:

```
else    // If not first JPEG             
{                 
    fclose(jpeg0);
```

if your (for instance) working with the 3rd file, then `jpeg0` is already closed, resulting in a run time error. Suggest removing the statement:

```
FILE *jpeg0;
```

and always using `jpegn`

regarding;

```
else    // If already found JPEG         
{             
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, jpegn);         
}
```

on the first output file, `jpegn` is not set, so this results in a crash. Again, ONLY use `jpegn` for all output file operations.

regarding:

```
fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, jpegn);
```

this returns the number of (second parameter) amounts actually written, so this should be:

```
if( fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, jpegn) != 512 ) { // handle error }
```

the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers, like 512. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: Part of the reason why I used sprintf and malloc was because the problem set I am working on wants me to use it in my code. And I initialised my file pointers to NULL because I was told that it's good practice. But it seems like it's giving me problems instead of preventing them. But your suggestions make a lot of sense. There were several points you made that I didn't even know were allowed for the conditional statements, functions etc. I clearly need to study the documentation. Thank you for being so helpful to a newbie.

Comment: If you see my answer as helpful, the please click the up arrow next to the answer

Comment: I did, but it says that I don't have enough points for my upvote to  be shown publicly.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite many issues on your code. I am surprised if valgrind didn't identify these out.

First is this:

```
    if(fopen(argv[1],"r") == NULL) // Checks if the image can be opened for reading 
    {
        printf("This image cannot be opened for reading\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    FILE *forensic_image = fopen(argv[1],"r");  // Opens the image inputted and stores it in a new file
```

This is not fatal, but you opened the same file twice and discard the first file pointer. But the one with similar pattern below is definitely a memory leak:

```
    BYTE *buffer = malloc(512 * sizeof(BYTE)); // Dynamically creates an array capable of holding 512 bytes of data
    
    if(malloc(512*sizeof(BYTE)) == NULL) // Checks if there is enough memory in the system
    {
        printf("System error\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Here you allocated 512-bytes twice and keep only the first allocation in the pointer `buffer`, while the second allocation is lost.

And then this:

```
    char *filename = NULL;

    // ...   
    
    sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", JPEG_num);
```

you are writing a string to an unallocated memory!

and also the lines:

```
        else    // If already found JPEG
        {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, jpegn);
        }
```

How can you guarantee `jpegn` is a valid file pointer? Probably never because I see in your code that `JPEG_num` will always be 0. The part of `else` marked by `// If not first JPEG` is dead code.