# CS50 pset4 recover - fread in while loop only reaches end after generating 7168 jpegs

Tags: c, cs50

So I'm doing the CS50 pset4 recover task (where you need to search for jpg files on a memory card and whenever you find one- you open a new file and write the jpg found to the new file). For some reason the `fread` in my `while` loop on line 31 continues until 7168 images are generated (there should only be 50). My understanding was that when `fread` hits the end of the file it stops returning the number of items that were read. For reference the full task description can be found here: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/recover/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint8_t  BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: recover [filename]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *filename = argv[1];

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", filename);
        return 2;
    }

    BYTE buffer[512];
    int counter = 0;
    char *imagename = malloc(sizeof(char)*12);
    FILE *img = NULL;

    while (fread(&buffer, 512, 1, file) == 1)
    {
        if (counter > 50) // added to break while loop after 50 jpegs have been generated
        {
            break;
        }

        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            if (counter > 0)
            {
                fclose(img);
            }
            sprintf(imagename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            img = fopen(imagename, "w");
            if (img == NULL)
            {
                fclose(file);
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", imagename);
                return 3;
            }
            fwrite(&buffer, 512, 1, img);
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (counter > 0)
            {
                fwrite(&buffer, 512, 1, img);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(img);
    free(imagename);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: `char *imagename = malloc(sizeof(char)*12);` -> `char imagename[12];`. It's pretty pointless to dynamically allocate a fixed size of memory here rather than declaring a fixed size array in the first place.

Comment: Add a link to the complete description of the 'CS50 pset4 recover task'.

Comment: Aside: please change `&buffer` to `buffer` in calls to `fread()` and `fwrite()`. Also you can move `fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img);` out of the conditional blocks. It needs to be done once for every `fread()` whether to the current file, or the one you just opened.

Comment: Aside if you are using MS VC please open the files in binary mode.

Comment: Does the combined size of the 7168 files match the size of the input file (i.e. wrong splitting) or are excess files created?

Comment: @Gerhardh excess files are created - the first 50 files are the correct jpegs that the program should output. The rest of the files don't open correctly.

Comment: OT: regarding; `printf("Usage: recover [filename]\n");` 1) Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.   2) an executable can be run under (almost) any name.  Best to not hard code the name.  Suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s [filename]\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", filename);` when an error indication is returned from a C library function, should output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest: `perror( "fopen for input file failed" );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `char *imagename = malloc(sizeof(char)*12);`  1) in C, the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression. 2) the heap allocation functions can fail.  debugging such an event can be very difficult.  Therefore, always check (!=NULL) the returned value.  If the function failed (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed")` to inform the user of the failure and the reason the system thinks the failure occurred

Comment: regarding: `char *imagename = malloc(sizeof(char)*12);`  why use dynamic memory allocation?  a simple: `char imagename[12];`  would work just fine  and is easily reusable for for each recovered image

Comment: regarding; `fwrite(&buffer, 512, 1, img);`  1) a bare reference to an array name degrades to the address of the array.  I.E. do not insert a `&` before the array name. 2) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.    Suggest: `size_t success = fwrite( buffer, 512, 1, img ); if( ! success ) { perror( "fwrite failed" ); }`

Comment: You may find [cs50 pset4 Recover - why does writing entire file to memory fail check50?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62608167/3422102) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. does not include header files that are not used
3. performs the desired functionality
4. honors the right margin (column 72 or 80)

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s [filename]\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    FILE *fpin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if ( ! fpin )
    {
        perror( "fopen for input file failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    unsigned char buffer[512];
    int counter = 0;
    char imagename[12];
    
    FILE *fpout = NULL;

    while (fread(&buffer, 512, 1, fpin) == 1)
    {
        if(   buffer[0] == 0xff 
           && buffer[1] == 0xd8 
           && buffer[2] == 0xff 
           && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            if (counter > 0)
            {
                fclose( fpout );
            }
            
            sprintf(imagename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            fpout = fopen(imagename, "w");
            if ( ! fpout )
            {
                perror( "fopen for write of individual image file failed" );
                fclose( fpin );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            counter++;
        }
        
        size_t success = fwrite( buffer, 512, 1, fpout );
        if( ! success )
        {
            perror( "write of individual image record failed" );
            fclose(fpin);
            fclose(fpout);
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    fclose(fpin);
    fclose(fpout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get a segfault when I try to run the above - any ideas?

Comment: I examined the `card.raw` file.  It contains a LOT of leading 0x00 bytes.  (not what was expected)  You will need to insert a loop, inputting a byte at a time, until the first .jpg header byte  `0xFF` is encountered, then use `ungetc()` to restore that one byte, then enter the `while()` loop.  note: there is a "cs50.ly/surprise"  bit of text that your 'discard leading  trash' code will need to step right through, only stop when a 0xFF is encountered

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about CS50 pset4 recover task, but the logic wise i have below comment:

Why are you not increasing the `counter` variable in `else` part?

Lets say your condition `if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)` is true for some image , then your `counter` variable will be incremented, after that, for all the images you are writing them `fwrite(&buffer, 512, 1, img);` in `else` part irrespective of any condition this will increase the number of images without increasing the count.

Comment: Questions for clarification should be asked in comments, not in answers. In this case the answer is because `counter` is used to count detected jpeg files. If no new header is found, no new file is detected and `counter` must not be increased. The `else` part is for the blocks of the jpeg file that are not the first one containing the header.