# How could count number of data blocks that have a file?

Tags: c

I have to make a program that extract images from a RAW file. It's specified that the system file is fat32 and blocks of data are 512 bytes. The below program works, at least with the file that is provided for testing, but when i try to use RAW files that I found on the internet, not works and yields a segmentation fault error. Valgrind report some bytes still reachable.

I think I'm reading less or more bytes that the block size for data in the file, so:

How could I know the size of each block data inside the file?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for two arguments
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the forensic image
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "It's not possible open the file :(\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // Initialize values
    int count = 0;
    BYTE buffer[512];
    char filename[8];
    FILE *out = NULL;

    // Read blocks of data from forensic image
    while (fread(&buffer, sizeof(BYTE), sizeof(buffer), file))
    {
        // Check if there is a JPG signature
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8
            && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            // If isn't first loop, close previous output file
            if (count !=  0)
            {
                fclose(out);
            }

            // Save name for current output file
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count++);

            // Open output file
            out = fopen(filename, "w");

            // Check if file is right
            if (out == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "File could not open :(\n");
                return 3;
            }

            // Write data to output file
            fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(BYTE), sizeof(buffer), out);
        }
        // If isn't first loop, write data
        else if (count != 0)
        {
            fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(BYTE), sizeof(buffer), out);
        }
    }

    fclose(out);
    fclose(file);

}
```

Comment: What line is the segmentation fault happening on?

Comment: Line 32. The condition of while loop.

Comment: You cannot use `fread` correctly unless you validate the return. (more than `true` / `false`) What happens when there is only 1-byte left in the input stream `file`? Are `buffer[1 .. 3]` valid indexes in that case? What happens when you attempt to `fwrite (... sizeof(buffer) ...)` bytes in that case? Is this the CS50 "Recover" problem? Looks familiar. If it is, you may find it helpful to enter `"CS50 Recover"` in the search box at the top of the page. There are a number of questions dealing with that problem already addressed.

Comment: The answer to [cs50 pset4 Recover - why does writing entire file to memory fail check50?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62608167/3422102) is one that comes to mind.

Comment: Yes, it's CS50 recover. The pset is done, all checks are right. Just I wanted to try with other files but not worked. I want to solve for personal purposes.
Thank you very much for your suggestions.