# CS50 Week 4 - Recover - Valgrind Heap Summary Error

Tags: c, cs50

C Code:

This is the c code of the problem there is a card.raw file that contains the images.

```
// Include necesary libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Constants
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
int const BLOCK_SIZE = 512;

// Main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover file.raw");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open file
    FILE *raw_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    // If file could not be opened warn the user
    if (raw_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened");
        return 1;
    }

    // Generate jpg
    // Create couter for name of jpg
    unsigned int img_id = 0;

    // Create block for storing the blocks of read data
    BYTE block[BLOCK_SIZE];

    // Create the file pointer for the generated jpgs
    FILE *jpg_file = jpg_file = fopen("000.jpg", "w");

    // Loop thru all blocks
    while (fread(block, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, raw_file) == BLOCK_SIZE)
    {
        // Run if block start is jpg header
        if (block[0] == 0xff && block[1] == 0xd8 && block[2] == 0xff && (block[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            // Close only when a file has been opened
            if (jpg_file != NULL)
            {
                fclose(jpg_file);
            }

            //Generate the filename to follow the pattern ###.jpg where ###
            //is a 3 dijit number that is the id (the nth image) of the image
            char filename[8];
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", img_id);

            // Create a jpg in base of the filename
            jpg_file = fopen(filename, "w");

            // Increase img id
            img_id++;

            // If file could not be created warn the user
            if (raw_file == NULL)
            {
                printf("File could not be created");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        // If a file has already been opened write the data to it
        if (jpg_file != NULL)
        {
            fwrite(block, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, jpg_file);
        }
    }

    // Close file to prevent memory leaks
    fclose(raw_file);
}
```

Valgrind Check:

```
==7293== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7293== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7293== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7293== Command: ./recover card.raw
==7293== 
==7293== 
==7293== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7293==     in use at exit: 472 bytes in 1 blocks
==7293==   total heap usage: 104 allocs, 103 frees, 237,536 bytes allocated
==7293== 
==7293== 472 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==7293==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7293==    by 0x4A086CD: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==7293==    by 0x4A086CD: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:86)
==7293==    by 0x1092EB: main (recover.c:58)
==7293== 
==7293== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7293==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7293==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7293==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7293==    still reachable: 472 bytes in 1 blocks
==7293==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7293== 
==7293== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==7293== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Everything works except for that heap issue any help is appreciated!

This is some filler text because in the code there are the comments but it says 'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.' so yea.

Comment: you never close `jpg_file` and use reuse this pointer (opening another file). BTW  `FILE *jpg_file = jpg_file = fopen("000.jpg", "w");` is weird

Comment: `FILE *jpg_file = NULL;` was what I supposed to say it was a leftover of a copy and paste try to fix, and doesn't `if (jpg_file != NULL) fclose(jpg_file);` close the file if the pointer is not NULL?

Comment: You close `jpg_file` only when a new block begins, but you don't close the last instance after the loop. And there's more copy-and-pasting gone wrong: After you open `jpg_file`, you check whether `raw_file` is null.

Comment: There are many answers to 'recover' on this site. You really don't need to allocate storage, but it is up to you. You can search "`[cs50] recover`" in the search box to find the other answers to compare. One is [CS50 Recover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62608167/3422102).

Comment: You're right i forgot to close the last file after the loop thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer just put a `fclose(jpg_file);` at the end the file gets closed only at the start of the loop so when it ends it does not get closed.

```
// Include necessary libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Constants
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
int const BLOCK_SIZE = 512;

// Main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover file.raw");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open file
    FILE *raw_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    // If file could not be opened warn the user
    if (raw_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened");
        return 1;
    }

    // Generate jpg
    // Create couter for name of jpg
    unsigned int img_id = 0;

    // Create block for storing the blocks of read data
    BYTE block[BLOCK_SIZE];

    // Create the file pointer for the generated jpgs
    FILE *jpg_file = NULL;

    // Loop thru all blocks
    while (fread(block, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, raw_file) == BLOCK_SIZE)
    {
        // Run if block start is jpg header
        if (block[0] == 0xff && block[1] == 0xd8 && block[2] == 0xff && (block[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            // Close only when a file has been opened
            if (jpg_file != NULL)
            {
                fclose(jpg_file);
            }

            //Generate the filename to follow the pattern ###.jpg where ###
            //is a 3 dijit number that is the id (the nth image) of the image
            char filename[8];
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", img_id);

            // Create a jpg in base of the filename
            jpg_file = fopen(filename, "w");

            // Increase img id
            img_id++;

            // If file could not be created warn the user
            if (raw_file == NULL)
            {
                printf("File could not be created");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        // If a file has already been opened write the data to it
        if (jpg_file != NULL)
        {
            fwrite(block, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, jpg_file);
        }
    }

    // Close file to prevent memory leaks
    fclose(raw_file);
    fclose(jpg_file); // Here is the fix to the problem

}
```